# java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException when reading a csv file

Tags: java, scala, file, csv, java-io

I am trying to read values of a csv file in scala.

```
val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile(destFile);
for (line <- bufferedSource.getLines) {
      rows += line.split(",").map(_.trim)
}
```

However when I am doing io.Source.fromFile(destFile); I am getting an exception

```
java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:281)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:339)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
at scala.io.BufferedSource$BufferedLineIterator.hasNext(BufferedSource.scala:70)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:929)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:929)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1417)
at TestFileProcessZip7z$.$anonfun$main$1(TestFileProcessZip7z.scala:79)
at TestFileProcessZip7z$.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(TestFileProcessZip7z.scala:34)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
at TestFileProcessZip7z$.main(TestFileProcessZip7z.scala:34)
at TestFileProcessZip7z.main(TestFileProcessZip7z.scala)
```

()

How do I resolve the above issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the encoding of the file? What's the default encoding of your platform?

Comment: Is there a way I can find the encoding of the file on mac OS?

Comment: [`file`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file)

Comment: I did file -I /path_to_my_file/file.csv and found the charset=binary, if that helps in any way

Comment: That means that the file doesn't match any known character encoding - my guess is the file is corrupt or doesn't contain text data.

Comment: Is there a way in scala by which we can extract all the files which are present in a .7z file. I am having a tough time using SevenZArchiveEntry api.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving charset to **ISO-8859-1** 
val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile(destFile, "ISO-8859-1");